# graphql playground behaving weirdly running on heroku

Tags: heroku, apollo-server

So i have an apollo-server running using apollo-server-express:

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000
const graphqlPath = process.env.GRAPHQL || 'graphql'
const app = express()

app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyParser.text({ type: 'application/graphql' }))

const gqlServer = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs: schema,
  resolvers,
  context: {
    me: users[1]
  },
  debug: true,
  tracing: true
})

gqlServer.applyMiddleware({ app, path: `/${graphqlPath}` })

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`graphql listening on port ${PORT}`))

module.exports = app
```

it runs perfectly on localhost, but deploying it to heroku, it becomes weird when i run the playground:

- it says Server cannot be reached
- I can't get the schema
- the queries run (sometimes) and immediately after i see the result, it changes to that json error object
- when i copy the curl request, and run it on my terminal, i always get the result without any problems

[image]

Here's a sample of the console errors:

> POST <graphql_server_url> 400 (Bad Request)
>   Error: Response not successful: Received status code 400

Answer (score 6):

Try adding introspection and playground to your ApolloServer config and set to true.  They get turned off automatically when the Node environment is set to production, but this way you can enable it in prod.  Reference: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/v2/testing/graphql-playground/#enabling-graphql-playground-in-production

```
const gqlServer = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs: schema,
  resolvers,
  context: {
    me: users[1]
  },
  debug: true,
  tracing: true,
  introspection: true,
  playground: true
})
```

Answer (score 4):

adding `introspection: true` to new ApollowServer object will solve the porblem